# Explanation on the type of Concat method

Tags: haskell, concatenation

Can someone please explain to me why the type of the source list in  my implementation of concat does not work ?

```
conc::[[a]]->[a]
conc xs@(x1:xs')=foldr (:) [] xs
```

Why should the source list be `[a]` and not `[[a]]` ? If i want to concat `[[1,2],[3,4]]` isn't the type `[[a]]` not `[a]` and the element type is `[a]`.

I get the following error :

```
Couldn't match type `a' with `[a]'
      `a' is a rigid type variable bound by
        the type signature for:
          conc :: forall a. [[a]] -> [a]
```

Comment: Well, source list is [[a]] not [a] so I'm not sure that I understand your question?

Comment: I get the error that i just posted above.

Comment: Yes i do expect that to happen.

Comment: Perhaps you meant to `foldr (++)` instead of `foldr (:)`.

Comment: `foldr (:) [] xs == xs` is  `True` for any `xs`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually compiler show the useful hint in the error (actually a couple lines lower, than the message, that you've posted)

```
Expected type: [a]
Actual type: [[a]]
```

In the following code the argument is indeed of type `[[a]]`, but the result is also of type `[[a]]`, which conflicts with the type definition:

```
conc :: [[a]] -> [a]
conc xs@(x1:xs') = foldr (:) [] xs
```

`xs` in the code is of type `[[a]]` and you're iterating over it using `foldr` and add every element, which is of type `[a]` to a list. As a result, you'll receive a list of type `[[a]]`.

Comment: Well that is what i am trying to understand .You are removing a set of brackets when concatenating.So from [[a]]  shouldn't it become  [a] ?

Comment: Yes, it should. But in your implementation it doesn't become `[a]`, it remains `[[a]]`

Comment: Well if i  apply the cons operator for [[1,2],[3,4]] does it not translate into [1,2]:[3,4]:[] ?

Comment: It does, and `[1,2]:[3,4]:[]` is equal to `[[1,2], [3,4]]` isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

`foldr (:) [] xs == xs` is  `True` for any `xs`. This means that `foldr (:) []` is an identity function on lists. This fact is widely known, part of Haskell lore so much so that `foldr (:) []` automatically reads as `id` in the mind of an experienced Haskell programmer.

One way of seeing `foldr c n` is as replacing the "cons" (i.e. `(:)`) with `c` and the `[]` with `n`, in a given list. Replacing `(:)` with `(:)` and `[]` with `[]` is obviously going to be changing nothing:

```
[a, b, ..., z]  ==>  a : b : ... : z : []  ==  [a, b, ..., z]
```

Replacing `(:)`s with `(++)` on the other hand, will get all the lists inside the input list concatenated together into one:

```
[a, b, ..., z]  ==>  a ++ b ++ ... ++ z
```

which is what you wanted to achieve.

So the correct implementation for `concat` with `foldr` is `foldr (++) []`.